# Storeing a users input as a string in JAVA

Tags: java

Firstly I am very new to JAVA, so I apoligise if I am not quick to pickup on something.

In the example below how could I store the user's input to a string as well as return it?

```
    Scanner inputme = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println(inputme.nextLine());
```

I was thinking something along the lines of:

```
inputme.WritetoString(thestringname);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use an intermediate variable:

```
Scanner inputme = new Scanner(System.in);
String line = inputme.nextLine();
// Do whatever in between
System.out.println(line);
```

Then the `line` variable is a String containing... the line :)